# How to run a single run non networked/non scaling docker application on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I've written some application code that takes around a day to run. I've developed it in a docker container such that my colleagues and I can be sure the environment is right and all the other benefits docker provides when it's run.

The task isn't a web service or providing a service to another application.

To avoid having to run it locally I'd like to deploy the image into AWS have the control to run the image while passing some environment variables and arguments to the entry point defined in my Dockerfile.

I'd like to avoid having to run my own ec2 instance to host docker to then run the code as the point is the image is self-contained. So I've been looking on AWS for a solution and it really doesn't seem set up for this kind of work.

ECR and ECS is the suggested method of hosting and using a docker image, but, it is completely focused on a cluster/group of networked images intending to provide a service and as such is really over top and I can't get it to perform my task. (after pushing my image and creating a new cluster with 1 desired container with the entry point set to the one I'd need at the moment)

Though there seems to be a section to add in entry point information/cmd and set up volumes it seems far away from the interface I'd expect with a simple `docker run IMAGE arg`

AWS beanstalk requires code source to be compressed and hosted on s3 and still has a focus on service as a cluster which isn't much better.

I'd like to just be able to run a docker image without having to manage an ec2 instance. Is this possible?

If not, is there a simple way to trigger the instance to stop when the docker image has completed?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like AWS Fargate is what you are looking for:

> Choose AWS Fargate to launch their containers without having to
>   provision or manage EC2 instances. If you require greater control of
>   your EC2 instances to support compliance and governance requirements
>   or broader customization options, then use ECS or EKS without Fargate.
>   Use EC2 for GPU workloads, which are not supported on Fargate today.

https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

Comment: From what I understand, Fargate is a technology that ECS is running on and not a service you can interact with directly through the console/cli? As in, its the ECR and ECS solution I was mentioning